# bulk insert in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I am trying to upload a excel sheet in database table. i am converting the excel rows to hibernate entity and trying to save it in database. to achive this i am facing problem. there are few db constraint like unique or composite key etc.  but user can upload any sheet. so if a perticular row is failed to insert then my requirment is that other row should be continued. and transaction should be saved.

```
`Session session=localSessionFactoryBean.getObject().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
fot(i=0;i<list.size();i++){
Long Id = (Long) session.save(list.get(i));
if (i % 50 == 0) {
                    session.flush();
                    session.clear();
                }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

`
here if a single row is failed then all rows are failing. i am getting 
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id  (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs) exception. please help to bulk upload.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you should use `try-catch` construct to continue inserting records even if some of them fail:

```
Session session=localSessionFactoryBean.getObject().openSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for(i=0;i<list.size();i++){
  try{
    Long Id = (Long) session.save(list.get(i));
  } catch(Exception e){
    //nop  
  }
  if (i % 50 == 0) {
     session.flush();
     session.clear();
     tx.commit();      
  }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: no it is not working the block where there is an exception is failing

Comment: don't flush the Session after an exception occurs

Comment: @ER.k.mukherjee Try now.

Comment: no not working, while keeping the tx.commit(); and session.flush(0 outside of try catch will throw exception to parent method and loop will be broken

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate doesn't allow to flush the session after an exception occured (you should see message `don't flush the Session after an exception occurs` in stacktrace), so a way to proceed can be that:

Split your `list` in chunks of 50 elements and try to save every chunk in a single transaction:

- if everything went fine just commit and proceed to next chunk.
- if an error occurred, rollback transaction and restart chunk BUT *save every single element of failed chunk in a dedicated transaction*